# How can I animate an element added dynamically to a list, in Vue.js 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, css-transitions

I am working on a small **[Todo App](https://github.com/Ajax30/Vue-3-To-Do)** with Vue 3. I want the appending of a new to-do item to be smooth, not instantaneous.

For this purpose, I have added the class *active* to the latest to-do item:

```
<template>
  <ul class="todo-list" v-if=dataIsLoaded>
      <TodoItem v-for="(todo, index) in todos.slice().reverse()"
        :key="todo.id" 
        :class="{done: todo.completed, active: index == 0}" 
        :todo="todo" 
        @delete-todo="$emit('delete-todo', todo.id)"
        @toggle-todo="$emit('toggle-todo', todo)"
        />
    </ul>
    <div class="loader" v-else></div>   
</template>
```

In the CSS I have:

```
li:first-child {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-295px);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

li.active {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

It does not work as I <s>expected</s> hoped. It might be because the CSS is loaded late, it might be for another reason I was unable to figure out.

What is the easiest solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of Vue list transitions. I've simplified a bit your code for demonstration purposes. Also I've replaced your component `TodoItem` with a `li` tag (assumed that it contains a `li` as the root element).

```js
new Vue({
 el: "#app",
 data: {
    todos: [
     { id: 1, text: "Todo 1" },
     { id: 2, text: "Todo 2" },
     { id: 3, text: "Todo 3" }
     ]
  },
 methods: {
    add(){
    this.todos.push({ id: 4, text: "Todo 4"})
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.list-enter-active, .list-leave-active {
  transition: all 1s;
}
.list-enter, .list-leave-to /* .list-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-295px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <transition-group name="list" tag="ul">
      <li v-for="(todo, index) in todos.slice().reverse()"
        :key="todo.id" 
        >{{ todo.text }}</li>
   </transition-group>
    <button @click="add">Add</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to maximize `Vuejs` functionalities. You may want to checkout [List Transitions](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition-group.html#move-transitions). By adding a few additional CSS rules, it looks much better and even animating smoothly when the whole list is shuffled.

checkout snippet below related to your use case for demonstration.

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;

const App = {
  setup() {
    const idCounter = ref(0);
    const todos = ref([]);

    const add = () => {
      const id = idCounter.value + 1;
      const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (todos.value.length + 1));
      todos.value.splice(index, 0, { id, text: `Todo ${id}` });
      idCounter.value++;
    };

    const remove = (id) => {
      const index = todos.value.findIndex((todo) => todo.id === id);
      if (index !== -1) {
        todos.value.splice(index, 1);
      }
    };
    
    const shuffle = () => {
      todos.value = shuffleArray(todos.value);
    };

    // Helper function to shuffle an array
    const shuffleArray = (array) => {
      for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
      }
      return array;
    };

    // Initialize todos
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      add();
    }

    return {
      todos,
      add,
      remove,
      shuffle,
    };
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <button @click="add">Add</button>
      <button @click="shuffle">Shuffle</button>
      <transition-group name="list" tag="ul">
        <li v-for="todo in todos" :key="todo.id">
          {{ todo.text }}
          <button @click="remove(todo.id)">Remove</button>
        </li>
      </transition-group>
    </div>
  `,
};

createApp(App).mount('#app');
```

```css
.list-move,  /* apply transition to moving elements */
.list-enter-active,
.list-leave-active {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.list-enter-from,
.list-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(30px);
}

/* ensure leaving items are taken out of layout flow so that moving
   animations can be calculated correctly. */
.list-leave-active {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.4.8/vue.global.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```